# How to render array of objects in the same <li> tag in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, array.prototype.map

I got some nested arrays. Something like this: [Array(2), Array(2), ...] [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed3Kz.png)

Each subarray contains two objects with a "text" prop.

```
obj = {key: something, text: something}
```

Now I want to render each subarray's object prop into one < li > tag just like this:

```
1. Array <li key={}>{obj.text - obj.text}</li>
2. Array <li key={}>{obj.text - obj.text}</li>
```

and so on.

I tried this, but it just renders each obj.text to different lines.

```
array.map(nested => nested.map(item => <li key={item.key}>{item.text}</li>)
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: you're mapping your nested array to li items. Try moving the <li> tag up a level and mapping over nested array into same <li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the array with `Array.map()`, but instead of iterating the sub-array, extract the two items manually, and render them inside the list item. You can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) or the brackets notation.

**Note:** since both items have keys, I've combined both to create the list item's key. You can also use just the 1st or 2nd item.

```
array.map(([a, b]) => <li key={`${a.key}-${b.key}`}>{a.text} - {b.text}</li>)
```